# Storing a python set in a database with django

Tags: python, django, serialization, set

I have a need to store a python set in a database for accessing later.  What's the best way to go about doing this?  My initial plan was to use a textfield on my model and just store the set as a comma or pipe delimited string, then when I need to pull it back out for use in my app I could initialize a set by calling split on the string.  Obviously if there is a simple way to serialize the set to store it in the db so I can pull it back out as a set when I need to use it later that would be best.

Comment: Like your question. Would love to see what expert pythonistas have to say.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to persist a Python set?  Why not have a foreign key relation in the database with the correct constraints to make items unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your database is better at storing blobs of binary data, you can [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) your set. Actually, pickle stores data as text by default, so it might be better than the delimited string approach anyway. Just [pickle.dumps(your_set)](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) and [unpickled = pickle.loads(database_string)](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) later.

Comment: `pickle.dumps()` and `pickle.loads()` operate on strings (that's what the "s" is for) so these can go in `varchar` or other text columns as well

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options here, depending on what kind of data you wish to store in the set.

If it's regular integers, [CommaSeparatedIntegerField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) might work fine, although it often feels like a clumsy storage method to me.

If it's other kinds of Python objects, you can try [pickling](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) it before saving it to the database, and unpickling it when you load it again. That seems like a good approach.

If you want something human-readable in your database though, you could even [JSON-encode](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) it into a TextField, as long as the data you're storing doesn't include Python objects.

Comment: I think `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` is perfect when values from MultipleChoiceField needs to be saved to database.

Answer (score 1):

[Redis](http://redis.io) natively stores sets (as well as other data structures (lists, dicts, queue)) and provides set operations - and its rocket fast too. I find it's the swiss army knife for python development.

I know its not a relational database per se, but it does solve this problem very concisely.

Answer (score 0):

What about [CommaSeparatedIntegerField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield)?

If you need other type (string for example) you can create your own field which would work like `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` but will use strings (without commas).

Or, if you need other type, probably a better way of doing it: have a dictionary which maps integers to your values.